# How can I add a comand on my keyboard?

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I have ubuntu on my computer because I couldn't afford windows, but I do not know much about programming, I mostly use it for Uni, so, with google docs and OpenOffice I manage to supply my needs; however, I frequently found myself in need of some special characters, such as: α, β, γ, Δ,  ≥, ≤ and µ.

What I do is: google it, and copy-paste it on the document; is there a way  to add the combination on my keyboard, for example, if I press alt+B =  β

I mean, it isn't necessary, but It would make my life easier.

Comment: Search for "compose key Linux" on your favorite search engine to get some ideas. There is also the third level switch (AltGr) that is helpful for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce some of the characters using <kbd>AltGr</kbd> but not all of the ones you list.

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> = ß
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>+<kbd>underscore</kbd>   = ≥
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd>+<kbd>underscore</kbd>   = ≤

[This reference](https://www.alt-codes.net/triangle-symbols) is also a useful source for click and paste various symbols from the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks! at the end I decided to install greek as a second Keyboard layout, seemed easier than learning all those codes and combinatios.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all sorts of characters if you know the correct "Code point"

To input a code point you hold down Ctrl+Shift and type u####. Thats the letter 'u' and a 4 character code. To get the characters you have listed the code points are:

```
{ctrl-shift u03b1} α

{ctrl-shift u03b2} β

{ctrl-shift u03b3} γ

{ctrl-shift u0394} Δ

{ctrl-shift u03bc} μ
```

There is a full list of Greek and Coptic codes at https://codepoints.net/greek_and_coptic

I have't found a way of making that simpler like Alt B = β

Comment: Thanks! at the end I decided to install greek as a second Keyboard layout, seemed easier than learning all those codes.